# identity server 4 api client keeps returing 401 unauthorized

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have 3 different project

1. Identity server
2. Api Server (responsible for providing api for client)
3. Client Server (reponsible for representation)

to make a secure webapp i have decided to use identity server. My identity configuration is below

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new IdentityResource[]
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
        new ApiResource[]
        {
            new ApiResource(name: "web-api-rms", displayName: "Web API RMS")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new ApiScope[]
        {
            new ApiScope("web-rms"),
            new ApiScope("web-api-rms"),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "web-rms",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB86B0".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:1901/signin-oidc" },
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:1901/signout-oidc",
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:1901/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "web-rms", "web-api-rms" }
            }
        };
}
}
```

and my API server configuration is below

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                    .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                        options.Audience = "web-api-rms";
                    });
```

Now the problem is that when ever I try to access the API using bearer token it always return me a 401 unauthorized
How can I solve it??

Comment: What does the logs in the API say?

Comment: I found my answer. I just forgot to add scopes on ApiResources